# Python/Tkinter: The order of mouse events different in scrollbar widget

Tags: python, events, tkinter, scrollbar

I'm checking the mouse events when slider dragged by following code. I got different order of mouse event for different widgets.

For Canvas, it looks normal

```
<ButtonPress-1>
<B1-Motion>
...
<B1-Motion>
<ButtonRelease-1>
```

for Scrollbar, it looks wrong order

```
<B1-Motion>
...
<B1-Motion>
<ButtonRelease-1>
<ButtonPress-1>
```

```py
from tkinter import *

def start(event):
    print('<ButtonPress-1>')

def stop(event):
    print('<ButtonRelease-1>')

def motion(event):
    print('<B1-Motion>')

root = Tk()

canv = Canvas(width=600, height=400, scrollregion=(0, 0, 1200, 800))
canv.grid(row=0, column=0)
scrollY = Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL, command=canv.yview)
scrollY.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
scrollX = Scrollbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canv.xview)
scrollX.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
canv['xscrollcommand'] = scrollX.set
canv['yscrollcommand'] = scrollY.set

root.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", start)
root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", stop)
root.bind("<B1-Motion>", motion)

root.mainloop()
```

My question is why the order of mouse events for Scrollbar widget is wrong ? the same problem for slider drag and arrowheads click. Can it be set to normal as time sequence ? or can I just bypass the events after scrollbar actions done for slider drag or arrowheads click ?

Environment:

1. WIN10
2. Python 3.8.3
3. Tkinter TkVersion 8.6

Comment: When I run your code on OSX I get the exact same result for dragging over the scrollbar and over the canvas.

Comment: It seems it depends on the OS.

Comment: Update for the environments.

Comment: Intresting, if you do Button-3 it works normal. I assume there is something like wait_var() in the background that prevents to interrupt the scroll event.

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually not sure why this works, but with ttk it works fine.
I assume there is something like wait_var() in the background and the variable just changes after the Button is released.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def start(event):
    print('<ButtonPress-1>')

def stop(event):
    print('<ButtonRelease-1>')

def motion(event):
    print('<B1-Motion>')

root = Tk()

canv = Canvas(width=600, height=400, scrollregion=(0, 0, 1200, 800))
canv.grid(row=0, column=0)
scrollY = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL, command=canv.yview)
scrollY.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
scrollX = ttk.Scrollbar(orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canv.xview)
scrollX.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
canv['xscrollcommand'] = scrollX.set
canv['yscrollcommand'] = scrollY.set

root.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", start)
root.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", stop)
root.bind("<B1-Motion>", motion)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, it work fine for ttk.Scrolbar. But B3 not work in this case for B3 won't trigger the scrollbar drag. The problem is I cannot change Scrollbar to ttk.Scrollbar because the code is in a python library and not my code.

Comment: That wasnt possible with the tk.Scrollbar() either..

Comment: If ttk.Scrollbar work fine, does it mean a bug in tkinter Scrollbar ?